# Fragment doesnt render in localhost(First react app)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have here a simple react app but for some reason it doesnt render the contents of class COIN

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Ticker</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='root'></tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/babel">


class Coin extends React.Component{
  /*constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }*/
  render(){
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.name}</td>
        <td>{this.proper.ticker}</td>
        <td>{this.proper.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(

     <React.Fragment> 
      <Coin name='Bitcoin' ticker='BTC' price='$9999'/>
      <Coin name='Ethereum' ticker='ETH' price='$299'/>
      <Coin name='Ampleforth' ticker='AMPL' price='$3.99'/>
     </React.Fragment>,
      document.getElementById('root')
);      



</script>


  </body>

</html>
```

When I go to `localhost/reactivan/myfirstreact.html`all i see is the table heading

```
Name    Ticker  Price
```

Im new to react and i use as editor VirtualStudio, so i really dont know what i need to fix in order to render the content proper.

When i open the console i see those errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticker' of undefined
    at Coin.render (<anonymous>:45:179)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17295)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17245)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18755)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:182)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:231)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:286)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23338)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22292)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22265)
3react-dom.development.js:19662 The above error occurred in the <Coin> component:
    in Coin

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:19662
react-dom.development.js:22800 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticker' of undefined
    at Coin.render (<anonymous>:45:179)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17295)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17245)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18755)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:182)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:231)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:286)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23338)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22292)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22265)
```

and i also get this error:

```
You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
```

Im not sure if ths is because i didnt set up Virtual Studio correct or if i have a mistake in my code. I dont think my code is wrong because im following a tutorial and i copied it from there, so I assume its an error in my virtual studio set up:
I have never used Virtual Studio or react before

Comment: You have typos - change this.proper to this.props.

Comment: thank you dude, i was looking everywhere, but i always miss those fcking typos, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Debug step one: read the error!

`Cannot read property 'ticker' of undefined`

So search for your code for `ticker`.

Then you see `this.proper.ticker`.

Looks like a typo.

Change to `this.props.ticker` and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

change proper to   =>  props

```
  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Ticker</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='root'></tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/babel">


class Coin extends React.Component{
  /*constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }*/
  render(){
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.ticker}</td>
        <td>{this.props.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(

     <React.Fragment>
      <Coin name='Bitcoin' ticker='BTC' price='$9999'/>
      <Coin name='Ethereum' ticker='ETH' price='$299'/>
      <Coin name='Ampleforth' ticker='AMPL' price='$3.99'/>
     </React.Fragment>,
      document.getElementById('root')
);



</script>


  </body>

</html>
```